# cmake install with pkg_check_modules

Tags: installation, cmake, dependencies

After installing a package (let’s call it XXX) with cmake, xxx.pc in install/lib64/pkgconfig looks like:

```
prefix=/path/to/xxx/install
includedir=/path/to/xxx/install/include
libdir=/path/to/xxx/install/lib64
Name: xxx
Description: The xxx library
Version: 2.2.0
Cflags: -I/path/to/xxx/install/include
Libs: -L/path/to/xxx/install/lib64 -lxxx /path/to/scalapack/lib/libscalapack.a /usr/lib64/liblapack.so /path/to/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a -lgfortran -lm /path/to/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a -lgfortran -lm -lm
```

Now when I try to build another package using that installation of XXX using pkg_check_modules(XXX REQUIRED xxx), cmake sets XXX_LDFLAGS to:

```
/path/to/scalapack/lib/libscalapack.a;/usr/lib64/liblapack.so;/path/to/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a;-L/path/to/xxx/install/lib64;-lxxx;-lgfortran;-lm
```

That is it re-ordered the list of libraries with the .a first and the '-l' last. The problem is that now I am getting some undefined scalapack functions at link time in xxx since xxx comes after scalapack, but depends on scalapack.
Any idea how to fix that, either on the second package side or when generating the .pc on the XXX side?

Comment: "cmake sets XXX_LDFLAGS to..." - Not quite true. When extract information about the package, CMake sets variable `XXX_LDFLAGS` to exact content of "Libs" (returned by `pkg-config --libs`). But your code (correctly!) does NOT use `XXX_LDFLAGS`. Instead, it uses separately `-l` flags (returned by `pkg-config --libs-only-l`), `-L` flags (`pkg-config --libs-only-L`) and all other flags (`pkg-config --libs-only-other`). That is why `-l` flags is reordered after "non-l" flags. This simple fix would be to generate `xxx.pc` to contain all libraries with `-l` option.

Comment: Indeed, it would be the optimal solution. Does cmake provide functionalities to split a library name (with full path and .a extension) into something like -L/path/to/scalapack -lscalapack?

Comment: For extract components of an absolute path to the library, see [cmake_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html) command. Actually, I would expect that `-l` option could perfectly be usable with absolute paths too.